# Problem with CSS module not found when deploying to vercel

Tags: next.js, vercel

This is the error log. And I cannot for the life of me fix this. everything works fine in dev but on deployment it fails. :(

```
23:12:53.687    Failed to compile.
23:12:53.687    ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../styles/Homebody.module.css' in '/vercel/workpath0/components/Home'
23:12:53.687    > Build error occurred
23:12:53.688    Error: > Build failed because of webpack errors
23:12:53.688        at /vercel/workpath0/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:15:918
23:12:53.689        at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
23:12:53.689        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
23:12:53.689        at async /vercel/workpath0/node_modules/next/dist/build/tracer.js:3:470
23:12:53.704    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
23:12:53.704    npm ERR! errno 1
23:12:53.707    npm ERR! next_front@0.1.0 build: `next build && next export`
23:12:53.707    npm ERR! Exit status 1
23:12:53.707    npm ERR! 
23:12:53.707    npm ERR! Failed at the next_front@0.1.0 build script.
23:12:53.707    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
23:12:53.714    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
23:12:53.714    npm ERR!     /vercel/.npm/_logs/2021-02-24T23_12_53_708Z-debug.log
23:12:53.719    Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
```

Comment: is the name of your css module ```styles/Homebody.module.css``` correct? if it is, try ```yarn build``` on dev and see what is the output

Comment: The problem seems to be in the file path, remember you can use jsconfig or tsconfig depending on your extension to define the root path and therefore you can use `styles/`

Comment: It was all a case lettering issue. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this with adding correct referencing to my css module.

For example.

```
import styles from "./Something.module.css";
```

to

```
import styles from "../Something.module.css";
```

Adding a relative path to the module helps.

Answer (score 1):

One thing is to start all `.module.css` files with a capital letter. Sometimes. however, you will still get the same error. To make matters worse, the error keeps occurring for varying `.module.css` files. So sometimes you will get `A.module.css` not found, and another time you get `B.module.css` not found.

I then deleted `node_modules` and ran `npm i`. No result; same error.

What *did* work for me was to make a new project with:

```
yarn create next-app
```

…and then add all the files from the old module one by one while redeploying the app each time to check it still works.

This isn't elegant, but it's fast enough and it does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

`git config core.ignorecase false` revealed case mismatches in some of my filenames. The local filenames can be different than in your remote when git has `core.ignorecase` as `true`.

Source: [Vercel docs](https://vercel.com/guides/how-do-i-resolve-a-module-not-found-error)

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I hope I can help someone in the future!

I was able to solve this issue by moving my CSS module file out of a subfolder into the root Styles folder.

Before:

```
-Styles
--Pages
---FileName.module.css
```

After:

```
-Styles
--FileName.module.css
```

Answer (score 0):

If you could change `Homebody.module.css` to `homebody.module.css`, that should work.
It's the first letter capitalize issue.